# cmake error ''ld: framework not found -lCoreFoundation" when compile the Node source code on Mac

Tags: c++, node.js, macos

I want to compile node in `CLion`, so I make a `CMakeLists.txt` file by gyp, but this error occurred:

```
ld: framework not found -lCoreFoundation
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [node] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/node.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/node.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

The part of `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(node
-Wl
  cares
  v8_libplatform
  openssl
  zlib
  http_parser
  libuv
  v8_base
  v8_libbase
  v8_snapshot
-Wl
  -framework CoreFoundation
  -lm
)
```

Comment: the error occured in osx 10.11.2

Comment: i've created a [document](https://gist.github.com/lev-kazakov/10f8be60d100d2f1cce54a6b312fcd12) on building node source on mac. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`"-framework CoreFoundation"` needs to be in quotes, otherwise CMake interprets `CoreFoundation` as a library name and puts `-lCoreFoundation` into the command line in its place. So, the command line becomes `-framework -lCoreFoundation`. Putting quotes around the construction, prevents this substitution.